Prevent pushing a merge of the remote main branch into a local main branch in gitlab
I need a way to prevent pushing a merge of the remote main branch into a local main branch in gitlab. When I say "main" branch it could be any branch, it is just an example, as long as both remote and local branches have the same name.
This happens very easily:
The remote main branch is ahead of someone's local branch. This someone, makes a local change, commits it, then tries to push, but of course he can't because
his copy is not up to date, then he just  pulls, which creates a merge from the remote main branch into his local branch, an then he pushes, his local main branch.
Remote main branch:
A-->B-->C-->D

Local main branch:
A-->B

Commit to local main:
A-->B-->E

Pull (fetch+merge):
A-->B-->E------>F
     \        /
      ->C-->D-

When you look at the git log, it looks like now this local main branch is the trunk of the tree, and the previous remote main branch transforms into something that looks like a feature branch.
This push has not actually rewritten the history, but it has rewritten the topology of the history.
Is there a name for that situation?
I want to disallow this and allow only the merge in the other direction, local branch merged into the remote branch. This keeps the original trunk as it was (the remote topology does not change), and the new commit looks like a feature branch, which it is exactly what it was:
A-->B-->C-->D-->F
     \         /
      -->E-----

I still want to allow merges from and into branches with other names, e.g. you can merge from main into dev or from dev into main and push it. I just want to disallow the push of a branch with the same name that will change the topology of the remote branch.
Why? Keeping the original topology is important because it shows that C and D in the example above were pushed (i.e. published) in the main branch. This means that probably the QA team tested them and maybe these changes were sent to our client. It also shows that this could never happen with E (only F could be tested and sent to the client). If we allow to rewrite the topology (putting E in the main line) all that information is lost.
We are using Gitlab, and I know that you can prevent this situation disallowing all pushes and work with merge requests. But I want to allow everyone to work from the command line and push to any branch, as long an they don't rewrite the history or its topology.
How can I configure that?

Try one of the commit ordering options to git-log.

I edited the question replacing "origin" with "remote" as @Schwern suggested.

It is not a matter of the order of the commits. I want to see ABCD in the same line in git log

Would you show an example using git log --oneline --decorate --graph?

The git log would look pretty much as my example but in vertical orientation instead of horizontal. I added a "why?" paragraph explaining why I think the topology of the tree is important

I think you are describing the same situation as in How can I prevent foxtrot merges in my 'master' branch?, which gives this a name.

Thanks! "Foxtrot merges" is the answer I was looking for. Once you know that, all solutions are easier to find :)

You have two problems.

fetch + merge creates an "update merge" that clutters history.
You're not using merge requests so you have little control over what gets merged.

The solution is...

Encourage fetch + rebase: git pull --rebase or set pull.rebase true.
Use merge requests with the "Merge commit with semi-linear history" merge method in your merge requests.

For people who are still partying like it's 1999 and want to do everything on the command line, there's a glab command line tool. But unless you have a very specific reason you want to do everything on the command line, I suggest letting go of this requirement. Merge requests are just too useful; they're a standard, documented, and featureful way to accept, review, and test contributions.
Solution Part 1: Encourage fetch + rebase
You could add a pre-receive hook to prevent pushes with this sort of merge, but then your contributors have to know how to undo their merges. It's relatively simple, rebase their branch, but a lot of people don't know that. They'll either bother you about it, or give up and not contribute.
# pushing was disallowed leaving us in this state after git pull merged

A - B - E - U [main]
     \     /
      C - D [origin/main]

# The user knows how to solve this by rebasing.
$ git rebase origin/main
A - B - C - D [origin/main]
             \
              E1 [main]

# Now the push succeeds.
$ git push
A - B - C - D - E1 [origin/main][main]

This illustrates another problem: if the local branch has just one commit you won't get the feature bubble you want. However, you can force a merge commit if you use merge requests! This will be a theme.
You can simplify this by having git pull do a fetch + rebase. git pull --rebase or setting git config pull.rebase true.
# Branch is out of date
origin
A - B - C - D [main]

local
A - B [origin/main]
     \
      E [main]


# Branch is up to date
$ git pull --rebase

origin
A - B - C - D [main]

local
A - B - C - D [origin/main]
             \
              E1 [main]

Because this can rewrite history, pushes should be done with git push --force-with-lease.
You can't force people to do this, but you can encourage it.
You can't merge into a remote branch

I want to disallow this and allow only the merge in the other direction, local branch merged into origin remote tracking branch.

You can't merge into a remote tracking branch. Their purpose is to track the state of the repository. If you merge into the remote tracking branch it no longer tracks the remote. Git won't even let you switch to a remote branch.
> git switch origin/master
fatal: a branch is expected, got remote branch 'origin/master'

Solution Part 2: Merge commit with semi-linear history

I know that you can prevent this situation disallowing all pushes and work with merge requests.

You should do exactly that, at least for the main branch, for a myriad of reasons! Making git log come out as you'd like is the least of them.
Set your merge method to be Merge commit with semi-linear history. This will prevent merges unless the branch can be fast-forwarded, which is good because it means the code you test in the merge request is the code you will merge. And it offers a simple rebase button for your contributors to update their branches via rebase.
